# WebService and database and user management

Tags: c#, sql-server, web-services, visual-studio-2010, authentication

I'm new to WebServices.
I want to create (very simple) WebService application with database (maybe MS-SQL) and user authentication (log in, log out) and some function that check is user is logged in before returning any result.
I found this http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/WebServiceAuthentication.aspx
I don't want anyone doing my job for me. I just need some hints about how to begin with that.
I'll be using Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Ultimate.

How can I use this webservice in winforms application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Traditional Webservices (.asmx) have given way to the new WCF (Windows Communication Foundation) Services (.svc). These have a lot more granularity control over everything, which is a good and bad. If you aren't familiar with webservices already, I would say try to get the concepts right first - as in the high level architecture of how it works (communication, SOAP, and the protocols needed).

Then specifically for visual studio and how to create them, MSDN has a good starter tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t745kdsh.aspx (this is done the traditional .asmx way, which is not bad at all)

The codeproject URL you have is fine, but I think it requiures that you know the basic concepts first... and it is specifically for making an authentication web service. My take is if you know how to create 'a' webservice, then making the authentication ws will be very easy..

If you are interested in WCF services (which I recommend you hold of till later) this is a good reference as well: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms734712.aspx